# Is it possible to link to a bundled product with pre-selected options and quantity?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, bundled-product, parameter

I have read that we could have pre-selected configuration by using # (has tag) followed by attribute id = value id, but how can we achieve the same for a bundled product?
For example in the demo Magento store 
http://83.136.86.180/magento/ee11421/home-decor/electronics/mp3-player-with-audio.html
How can I pre-select "Madison 8GB Digital Media Player" with 5 quantity plus "Madison Over-ear Headphone" with 3 quantity and the whole bundle with 2 quantity? 
[image]
I want to achieve the pre-selection by passing get parameter to the URL.